# Count and Group By Date but also have 3rd WHERE column

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have table like this:

```
CREATED         STATUS
--------------------------------    
12-Dec-20       Pending 
12-Dec-20       OnHold  
12-Dec-20       Pending 
12-Dec-20       OnHold  
12-Dec-20       Completed   
12-Dec-20       Completed   
13-Dec-20       Completed   
13-Dec-20       Completed   
14-Dec-20       Pending 
14-Dec-20       OnHold  
14-Dec-20       OnHold  
15-Dec-20       Pending 
15-Dec-20       Completed
```

Desired Output:

```
CREATED         TOTAL       COMPLETED
---------------------------------------
12-Dec-20       6           2
13-Dec-20       2           2
14-Dec-20       3           {0 or blanks are ok}
15-Dec-20       2           1
```

I can get first 2 columns with this:

```
select trunc(created), count(*)
from table1
group by trunc(created)
```

But I can't figure out how to add the 3rd column based on a *WHERE STATUS like 'Completed'* clause.

Do I need a Group By Set, or an Inner Join?
My data set is small, < 100,000 items.  Simplicity is preferred over performance for this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get using case statement :

```
select created , count(1) as Total , 
       sum(case when status = 'Completed' then 1 else 0 end ) as Completed
  from table1
 group by created
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a nice use case for the pivot operator:

```
select * 
from data 
pivot ( count(*) as count 
   for (status) in (
      'Pending' AS pending, 
      'OnHold' AS onhold, 
      'Completed' AS completed
   ) 
);
```

| CREATED | PENDING_COUNT | ONHOLD_COUNT | COMPLETED_COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12-DEC-20 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 14-DEC-20 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 15-DEC-20 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 13-DEC-20 | 0 | 0 | 2 |

If you really need the total on the row it get a little more complicated

```
select * 
from ( 
  select created,status,count(*) over( partition by created) total_count 
  from data )
pivot ( count(*) as count 
for (status) in (
  'Pending' AS pending, 
  'OnHold' AS onhold, 
  'Completed' AS completed
 ) ) 
 order by created;
```

| CREATED | TOTAL_COUNT | PENDING_COUNT | ONHOLD_COUNT | COMPLETED_COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12-DEC-20 | 6 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 13-DEC-20 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 14-DEC-20 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 15-DEC-20 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 2 |

You can play with it in this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5882e1e2100dc875cede0a84bd1dfac8)